When we are installing microcloud on ubuntu22.04 it's taking longer than usual while initialising microcloud
while installing microcloud and initialising it it's taking longer than usual while scanning local subnet on the machine so how can we overcome to this issue, is there anything we are missing or anything which is required but we are missing some configuration.
